# How to import a point file in autodesk 3d max?

Tags: 3d, autocad, autodesk

I have a text (.txt) file which contains 3d points in line delimited format like this:
0,0,0
1,0,0
3,2,5
I want to import these points in AutoDesk 3d max. These points doesn't form any shape i.e. they are not connected, I just want to visualize these points.
Can anybody help me. Thanks in advance :)

P.S: As i am generating this file in java code so I can easily put tags or some extra information in file as well or I can change file formats slightly to match any existing acceptable formats for AutoDesk 3d max.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see is to use Max Script. I suppose it will be easier to load points this way than try to reinvent a row format supported by 3ds max.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) I don't know anything about max script. Can you save me time because for you it might be like writing hello world program. no pressure :)

Comment: unfortunately I didn't go further than Hello World in Max Script ;) So I'm not a good helper in this language. Just try to google some examples in Max Script relative to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

firstly, i saved the file in .pts format
first record is the number of records in the file
subsequent contains; x,y,z,"something",r,y,b fields
you can make the remaining four fields "0".
save the file as a .pts file.
secondly, i created a recap project (you should have it as it comes with my 3ds max installation) and imported the file. save the project as .rcp file.
finally, in 3ds max, in create-->geometry-->point cloud object, load the rcp file.